# space between <span> and <section> / <footer> element

Tags: html, css

I have noticed a space between `span` and `section` element (also between `span` and `footer`) and can`t define what causes it.

```css
html {
    font-size: 1rem;
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
    padding-left: 20%;
    padding-right: 20%;
    --div-color: rgb(32, 30, 163);
    --sec-color: rgb(138, 24, 24);
}

main {
    padding: 1rem;
    border: solid 0.1rem green;

}

section {
    position: relative;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    border: solid 0.2rem var(--sec-color);
    width: 30rem;
    height: 20em;
}

h3 {
    color: purple;
    text-align: center;
    border: solid 0.2rem purple;
}

div {
    position: absolute;
    top: 5rem;
    left: 5rem;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 20rem;
    height: 10em;
    border: solid 0.2rem var(--div-color);
}

span.div-col, span.sec-col, span.main-col, span.foot-col {
    color: white;
    padding: 0rem 1rem;
}

span.div-col {background-color: var(--div-color);}
span.sec-col {background-color: var(--sec-color);}
span.foot-col {background-color: coral;}

span.main-col {
    position: relative;
    bottom: 18px;
    right: 17px;
    background-color: green;}

footer {
    margin-top: 2rem;
    color: coral;
    border: solid 0.2rem coral;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    
    <main>
        <span class="main-col">main</span>
        <h3>h3</h3>
        <section>
            <span class="sec-col">section</span>
            <div><span class="div-col">div</span></div>
        </section>

    </main>
    <footer>
        <span class="foot-col">footer</span>
    </footer>
```

Comment: "top", "bottom" and "margin-top" are the places in your css, where you should look for answer

Comment: its not `padding` , `margin` nor `border` in child element (`span`) nor the parents (`footer`, `section`)